# Add virtual layer to aggregate feature

Tags: qgis, sql, csv, query, virtual-layer

newbie here of `QGIS` here, I was trying to aggregate a feature from a CSV with no geometries. The query is very basic:

```
SELECT 
    "PROV",
    SUM("POP_2012") AS POP_2012
FROM "municipalities-tuscany"
GROUP BY "PROV"
```

but I'm stuck and cannot make it work: if I go to `Data Source Manager > Virtual Layer`, fill the form and set `Unique identifier column` equal to `PROV` the resulting layer shows only 1 instance (instead of 10), like I filtered it. If I try using `DB Manager > Virtual Layers` and open the `SQL Window`, I run and correctly visualize the query, but when I try to `Load as new layer`, set `Column with unique values` equal to `PROV` and click `Load` nothing happens. If I set no `Column with unique values` get nothing in both cases.

Comment: Which version of QGIS are u using ?

Comment: Using version `3.6`

Comment: Did u solve your problem ? Are you able to share your file ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your `unique identifier column` is set on a wrong variable type (string ?) : it should be an integer ... Don't u have a specific **numeric** ID for your 'provinces' ?

Comment: When you load a CSV into QGIS, it sometimes assumes every column is text. You can specify column type by creating a CSVT file, as explained here: https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/